# Include .exe file inside pypi package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I want to include an executable file inside my python package.

I'm using pyproject.toml with setuptools to build.

I tried to add a MANIFEST.in file with these lines:

```
include README.md
include LICENSE
recursive-include my_package/data *
```

and added these lines into my pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.setuptools]
[options.packages.find]
include = ["my_package/*"]
```

But the executable still didn't get included in my package.

Any idea how to solve this? or even better, because I know it is not a good practice to do this, how can I distribute my executable file through GitHub, because when others try to download it, it gets blocked by antiviruses and users can't download and install it.

Comment: The notation you are showing for `pyproject.toml` seems incorrect. It seems like valid TOML, but I am pretty sure that is not what you should be writing. https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html